# How to write this query sql in a DJANGO ORM

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I did this query to tested,
but now i need to included this in my view django and i don't know how to do this,

```
SELECT Referencia, Recebido, sum(contas_paga + Salarios_Comissao + encargos) as Contas, sum(Recebido - (contas_paga + Salarios_Comissao + encargos)) as Total
 FROM(
    SELECT 
            vrm.mes_referencia as Referencia,
            vrm.mapa_atual - (vrm.mapa_atual * 0.2) as Recebido,
            (SELECT SUM(valor) from contas_pagar_contas_pagar where to_char(dt_pagamento, 'MMYYYY') = vrm.mes_referencia) as contas_paga,
            (SELECT SUM(vl_valor_pago) from func_pagamentos_pagamentos where to_char(data_pagamento, 'MMYYYY') = vrm.mes_referencia) as Salarios_Comissao,
            (SELECT SUM(salario * 1.8) from func_pagamentos_pagamentos where to_char(data_pagamento, 'MMYYYY') = vrm.mes_referencia) as encargos

    FROM venda_resumo_mapa as vrm
    WHERE vrm.mes_referencia like '%2019%'
    group by (vrm.mes_referencia, vrm.mapa_atual)
    order by vrm.mes_referencia) as f

    group by (f.Referencia, f.Recebido)
```

**EDIT**

What I need to do is send the query result to my template, I never did it with raw, so:

```
    def get(self, request):
        data = {}
        ano = date.today().year

     data['consulta_situacao'] = resumo_mapa.objects.raw(
            '''SELECT vrm.mes_referencia as Referencia,
                      vrm.mapa_atual - (vrm.mapa_atual * 0.2) as Recebido,
               (SELECT SUM(valor) from contas_pagar_contas_pagar where
               to_char(dt_pagamento, 'MMYYYY') = vrm.mes_referencia) as contas_paga,
               (SELECT SUM(vl_valor_pago) from func_pagamentos_pagamentos where
        to_char(data_pagamento, 'MMYYYY') = vrm.mes_referencia) as Salarios_Comissao,
               (SELECT SUM(salario * 1.8) from func_pagamentos_pagamentos where
        to_char(data_pagamento, 'MMYYYY') = vrm.mes_referencia) as encargos

        FROM venda_resumo_mapa as vrm
        WHERE  vrm.mes_referencia like %s
        group by(vrm.mes_referencia, vrm.mapa_atual)
        order by vrm.mes_referencia)''', [ano]
        )

   return render(request, 'core/result.html', data)
```

**RESULT OF QUERY IN POSTGRESQL**

"012019"    "10000.00"  NULL
"022019"    "10000.00"  NULL
"032019"    "10000.00"  NULL
"042019"    "10000.00"  NULL
"052019"    "10000.00"  NULL
"062019"    "10000.00"  NULL
"072019"    "10000.00"  NULL
"082019"    "10000.00"  NULL
"092019"    "10000.00"  "50000" "50000"

"102019"    "10000.00"  "50000" "50000"

"112019"    "730276.0"  "592315.33" "137960.67"

Comment: Try to be more specific with your questions. All the information you require I believe is in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/

Comment: just use raw query, no point in trying to rewrite something in django ORM especially when its complex query and you already have it written in pure SQL. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/

Comment: @T.Opletal I'm tried do this, used raw query, but i don't know, why this dont returned expeted result.. but thanks i'll be trying.

Comment: @T.Opletal, I Received this msg : "Unable to get repr for <class 'django.db.models.sql.query.RawQuery'> "

Comment: If you have decided you'd like to try running this as a raw query, you should update your question and include the new code you're using. Without that, we can't help you with the the error message "Unable to get repr..."

Comment: Can you include the models you want to query?

Comment: @BillHuneke, i edit.

Comment: @vinh, I consult 3 models, i can to summary model, can be?

Comment: if your selects don't match to any model just use pure raw sql https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: If you want to use a django query, it would be helpful if you could include the models from your models.py, also if you want to use sql, the structure of the tables you are querying.

Comment: tks guys, but I was able to do the query work in my view.. with query Raw.